# Sorting Set<String> based on index names in java

Tags: java, sorting, set

My need is to sort Set data, based on specific index names. I have following data:

```
txt_4: somevalue
txt_2: somevalue
txt_1: somevalue
txt_0: somevalue
txt_3: somevalue
```

How can I sort this data? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Expected data after sorting:

```
txt_0: somevalue
txt_1: somevalue
txt_2: somevalue
txt_3: somevalue
txt_4: somevalue
```

Comment: Use a `TreeSet` and it will be sorted out of the box.

Comment: You should write your own `Comparator` and use a set that is ordered, e.g. `TreeSet`.

Comment: http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) object for that.

> TreeSet elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

```
     Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
     treeSet.add("txt_4: somevalue");
     treeSet.add("txt_1: somevalue");
     treeSet.add("txt_0: somevalue");
     treeSet.add("txt_3: somevalue");
     System.out.println(treeSet);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I want sort it like in `UPDATE` part of the question. I forgot to mention that while creating the question

Comment: @Dozent Please try my answer once.It will give, your expected result.

Answer (score 2):

A perfect solution using comparator: **The Alphanum Algorithm**

**People sort strings with numbers differently than software does. Most sorting algorithms compare ASCII values, which produces an ordering that is inconsistent with human logic. Here's how to fix it.** see: http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

**Davekoelle AlphanumComparator.java**: 
http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java

**Another alternative** is the ***se.sawano*** alphanumeric-comparator: https://github.com/sawano/alphanumeric-comparator

[image: AlphanumComparator]

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of Set is not defined; you cannot sort a set.

What you can do is add the elements from the set to a data structure that does define an order, for example List, and sort it instead.

Alternatively you could use a set implementation that already maintains its elements in sorted order. These include TreeSet and ConcurrentSkipListSet. But keep in mind that these implementations are more complex than what you may be using now and may slow down the rest of the program.

Comment: actually adding of set into the list ArrayList I was planning as a next step, but I want first order it like in `UPDATE` part of the question. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot affect the ordering of elements in a set. First add the elements of the set to the list, and then sort the list with [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is for?